# I am not able to solve the integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$I=\int { \frac { \sqrt { \sqrt { x } +\sqrt { x-1 }  }  }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  }  }$ $J=\int { \frac { \sqrt { \sqrt { x } -\sqrt { x-1 }  }  }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  }  } $ then I-J

I substituted $x=\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } $.

$I-J=\frac { \sqrt { \sec { \theta  } +\tan { \theta  }  } -\sqrt { \sec { \theta  } -\tan { \theta  }  }  }{ 1+\sec { \theta  }  } \times 2\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } \tan { \theta d\theta  } \\ I-J=\frac { \sqrt { \sec { \theta  } +\tan { \theta  }  } -\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { \sec { \theta  } +\tan { \theta  }  }  }  }{ 1+\sec { \theta  }  } \times 2\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } \tan { \theta d\theta  } \\ I-J=\frac { \frac { \sec { \theta  } +\tan { \theta  } -1 }{ \sqrt { \sec { \theta  } +\tan { \theta  }  }  }  }{ 1+\sec { \theta  }  } \times 2\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } \tan { \theta d\theta  } $
I am not able to solve further Please help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $\sqrt{\sec(\theta)  \pm \tan(\theta)} = |\sin(\theta/2) \pm \cos(\theta/2)|$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}I-J &=\int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}}}{\sqrt{x}+1}dx \\ &= \int\frac{\left(\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}}\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{x}+1}dx \\ &=\sqrt{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-1}}{\sqrt{x}+1}dx \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is some simplification available here as
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}}\right) &= \sqrt{1}
\end{align}

Since both $I$ and $J$ have these terms in, multiplication of these terms should give you something to work with once you have simplified the integrands using high school methods.